# android getting Manifest merger failed error in nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processF0F1DebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31
  >       is also present at [com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
  >       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:34 to override.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: As suggested in the error, try adding `tools:replace="android:value"`

Comment: can you share any demo manifest file

Comment: In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, just add `tools:replace="android:value"` under `<application..` tag.

Comment: <application
  android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  tools:replace="android:value" 
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding some code in app.gradle file issue resolved..

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support' && !requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.1'
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If updating the app.gradle doesn't fully solve the issue; you may have to do a search in your node_modules and specifically the plugins for any plugin that actually uses google services in their gradle.include files; they might be hard coded to use a `+` as the version, and you will need to change them to be also `16.+`

For more information, you can refer [here](http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=942).